# Best way to use groovy scripts in an application

Tags: scripting, groovy

I'm trying to use groovy scripts in my application. The problem is that GroovyScriptEngine#run always compiles the script, even if it was compiled in previous runs and hadn't changed since. Even if I set a physical output folder to save compilation results in the configuration.

What is the best way of working around this? The optimum for me is that I'm able to send the script with a folder containing precompiled results and no compilation is done (unless the script is modified of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution (hack) I used at last was to stream out the scriptCache variable using xstream and to read it back and set it in the object

Answer (score 2):

Grails 1.3.5 is using Groovy 1.7.5. In that Groovy version, `GroovyScriptEngine.run(..)` calls the following methods: `createScript(String, Binding)` --> `loadScriptByName(String)` --> `isSourceNewer(ScriptCacheEntry)`.

`isSourceNewer(ScriptCacheEntry)` is defined as (unfortunately, I didn't find a matching source file on the web):

```
protected boolean isSourceNewer(ScriptCacheEntry entry) 
    throws ResourceException {
    // ...

    for (String scriptName : entry.dependencies) {
        // ...
        return true; // without any further condition!
    }

    return false;
}
```

Which implements the (queer) logic "if a script has dependencies, it is newer than the cached script (and needs to be re-compiled)". That's not what the code is supposed to do; it's supposed to decide by modification time.

In [newer versions of `GroovyScriptEngine`, this has been corrected](http://fisheye.codehaus.org/browse/groovy/trunk/groovy/groovy-core/src/main/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.java?r1=10358&r2=10358&u=3) (there've been massive changes to the logic), but for now, you'd need to subclass `GroovyScriptEngine` and overwrite `isSourceNewer(ScriptCacheEntry)` to fix the logic yourself.

---

Edit: The bug has been [reported](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GROOVY-4492) and [fixed](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/attachment/51926/patchfile-all3.txt) in Groovy 1.7.6. - So try using Groovy 1.7.6 in your Grails *lib* folder.

Comment: Good to know, but this isn't my problem. My problem is the condition 'if (entry == null) return true;' at the start of isSourceNewer. Which means that a new GroovyScriptEngine will always compile the script, even if it was compiled previously and hadn't changed since

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps you, but you can alter GroovyScriptEngine's behaviour using CompilerConfiguration (see GroovyScriptEngine.[setConfig](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/GroovyScriptEngine.html#setConfig%28org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration%29)). There's an option CompilerConfiguration.[setRecompileGroovySource](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/org/codehaus/groovy/control/CompilerConfiguration.html#setRecompileGroovySource%28boolean%29), which can be used to set whether the sources will be reloaded and recompiled if they change. You can read more about CompilerConfiguration [here](http://www.google.cz/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=32&ved=0CB8QFjABOB4&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsubversion.assembla.com%2Fsvn%2Fkennyshop%2FMavenGwt%2FGroovy.for.Domain.Specific.Languages.pdf&rct=j&q=setRecompileGroovySource&ei=YX_7TJCGDZC38QPHruz5Cw&usg=AFQjCNHS0-c3ffKGrpW-3vec08F4tQGFBQ&cad=rja) (page 282).

Comment: Not sure what this flag does, but the problem is that GroovyScriptEngine#isSourceNewer uses a ScriptCacheEntry object. As its name suggest, it comes from a cache (a map). This map is empty when GroovyScriptEngine is created. No entry means isSourceNewer returns true, triggering compilation